# After call to ReadFile program hits breakpoint in debug_heap.cpp

Tags: c++, winapi

This function should read string from file and return it, but immediately after call to ReadFile program hits breakpoint in debug_heap.cpp file at line 985.

```
char* readFile()
{
char curDirectory[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, curDirectory);

char filePath[MAX_PATH];

char *name = "\\data.txt";

sprintf_s(filePath, "%s%s", curDirectory, name);

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(filePath, GENERIC_ALL, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DisplayError("Can't Create File");
    return NULL;
}

DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);

char *buffer = new char[fileSize / 2 + 1];
DWORD bytesReaded;

if (ReadFile(hFile, buffer, fileSize, &bytesReaded, NULL) == 0)
{
    DisplayError("Can't read File");
    return NULL;
}

buffer[bytesReaded] = '\0';

CloseHandle(hFile);

return buffer;
}
```

Comment: You try to read `fileSize` but you only allocate `new char[fileSize / 2 + 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your code writes beyond the end of buffer. You allocate `buffer` like this:

```
char *buffer = new char[fileSize / 2 + 1];
```

But then you attempt to read `fileSize` bytes from the file. Your allocation should instead be:

```
char *buffer = new char[fileSize + 1];
```

Some other comments:

- Your call to `sprintf_s` risks buffer overrun.
- Since you code in C++, use `std::string` and have that class manage buffers. You should do that for both `filePath` and `buffer`. That will allow you to avoid the leaks that your current code has. For instance, the failure return after `ReadFile` leaks memory. And it avoids placing a burden on the calling code to deallocate the memory.
- You also leak the file handle if your code takes the failure return after `ReadFile`.
- `bytesReaded` should be named `bytesRead`, to use the correct English word.
- There is no real reason to believe that the executable file is located in the current working directory.

Comment: Regarding the final bullet point, I told you that at your last question but perhaps it did not sink in. The current directory is not always the directory where the executable is located. Very often it is a different directory.

Comment: He is also leaking handles, better wrap these handles with a class or unique pointer with custom deleter.

Comment: How I'm leaking handles? The handle to file is closed at the end of the function.

Comment: see, that is why destructors were invented. because people were leaking in C and they didn't know why. what happens if `ReadFile` fails?

Comment: If you take the failure return after `ReadFile` then you leak memory and the file handle.